# Collapse list of JSON with nested structures into single data.frame

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I'm trying to parse some results from an API. The API returns a JSON result  for a given value. The API can only handle one value at a time so I `lapply` to get all the results. *<- If this is a bad start point happy to here a better way!*

Each JSON response has some nested info. I'm trying to get the data into one single data.frame with the nested structure resolved.

I've been playing around with jsonlite and purrr for much of the afternoon trying to get this working and ideally resilient.

**How does one successfully convert a nested json structure into a data.frame for multiple json documents/records using R?**

### MRE

```
library(jsonlite)
a <- LETTERS[1:5]
b <- letters[1:5]
c <- rep(data.frame(d=LETTERS[1:5]),5)

strSetup <- list(a, b, c)
dfSetup  <- data.frame(a, b, c)

jsonStr <- toJSON(rep(strSetup,3))

finalStr <- rbind(dfSetup,dfSetup,dfSetup)
```

I'm trying to go from `jsonStr` to `finalStr`.

Comment: Did you try `as.data.frame(fromJSON(jsonStr))`? It show 5 rows, 21 columns which I think is what you want.

Comment: When you say "The API returns a JSON result for a given value.", do you mean that it returns `toJSON(strSetup)` or `toJSON(dfSetup)`?

Comment: @parfait, jsonStr is intended to be representative of the Json I end up with in a list. Actual contents would be too long.

Comment: @fishtail,  unfortunately that puts everything as columns, not converting each Json entry into 5 rows and stacking them

Comment: @adam each call returns something like toJSON(strSetup)

Comment: So should line 9 of your example code be `jsonStr <- rep(toJSON(strSetup),3)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are storing all the JSON strings returned by the API into a character vector. That means that line 9 of your example is a little off and this should work.

```
library(jsonlite)
a <- LETTERS[1:5]
b <- letters[1:5]
c <- rep(data.frame(d=LETTERS[1:5]),5)

strSetup <- list(a, b, c)
dfSetup  <- data.frame(a, b, c)

jsonStr <- rep(toJSON(strSetup),3)

finalStr <- rbind(dfSetup,dfSetup,dfSetup)

finalStr2 <- do.call(
  what = rbind,
  args = lapply(
    X = jsonStr,
    FUN = function(x){
      data.frame(fromJSON(x))
      }
    )
  )

print(all(finalStr == finalStr2))
```

The caveat there is that `names(finalStr) != names(finalStr2)`. However, I don't think that's avoidable, since you indicated that the JSON string you're receiving from the API does not contain names.

If I misunderstood, please let me know.

Comment: It's coming in as a list due to the lapply  - each individual call returns a json object and I was looping through the input items to get the responses. I'm giving your code a whirl now though - I should be able to loop to a vector and if that makes life easier I'm all for it.

Comment: Ok. So you're using `lapply` with `FUN` equal to the function that pulls the JSON from the API? Can you wrap `unlist` around the `lapply` to convert it back to a vector?